# Как посчитать количество товаров для фильтра цены с колонками min, max?

Tags: sql

Пытаюсь посчитать количество товаров для фильтра цены. Исходный запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT 
MIN( pp.VALUE ) AS "min",
MAX ( pp.VALUE ) AS "max",
FROM "product" "p"
INNER JOIN "product_price" "pp" ON p.ID = pp.product_id
WHERE("p"."id" IN (1,2,3,4,5))
```

Добавляю COUNT, Group by - считает построчно, count = 1

```
SELECT 
p.id,
MIN( pp.VALUE ) AS "min",
MAX( pp.VALUE ) AS "max",
COUNT(p.id) as "count"
FROM "product" "p"
INNER JOIN "product_price" "pp" ON p.ID = pp.product_id
WHERE("p"."id" IN (1,2,3,4,5))
GROUP BY p.id
```

Можно ли в запросе sql получить count? Или только считать по ids товаров?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Answer (score 0):

1. Непонятен смысл использования `JOIN`, если по факту работа идёт только со второй таблицей;
2. Вы вероятнее всего откуда-то передаёте значения минимальной и максимальной цены, так зачем она в `SELECT`, когда должна быть в `WHERE`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [product_price]
WHERE [product_id] IN (*Нужные id*)
AND [VALUE] BETWEEN *Значение минимальной* AND *Значение максимальной*
```